# jquery setTimeout function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display success message for 5 seconds it displaying "wait" message but it not displaying "sent" message. I tried a lot but I failed. can you please help me? why my sent message is not displaying?

my timeout function is working but it executing hide 'Loading' line before finishing setTimeout function.
HTML code:

```
<div class="loading" style="display:none">
<h3 style="color:#000;font-size:24px;width:500px"><span id="wait">Please wait...</span><span id="sent" style="display:none">E-mail is sent</span><span id="error" style="display:none">Sorry Please try again</span></h3>
  <div class="l_main">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="quater">
      <span class="top"></span>
      <span class="bottom"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
  $('.loading').show();
  $("#wait").show();
  $.post(base_url+"index.php/myad/getphonenumber",{uniqueid:id,emailaddress:cemail},function(){
    $("#wait").hide();
    $("#sent").show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#sent").hide()
    }, 5000);
    $('.loading').hide(); 
  })
```

Comment: what is the issue you are seeing in console?

Comment: If your post request is failing, it is possible that it's not entering the function. You can use `console.log` to quickly verify this. Also look in the network tools to see what the status of the request is.

Comment: @user2181397 no

Comment: @Kimberly W it successfully working

Comment: @Donald Wu I just wrote success message and set ID sent

Comment: We need to see your HTML or it's hard to debug it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/9fvLtm5r/

Comment: @RushabhShah "but it executing hide 'Loading' line before finishing setTimeout " Your `$('.loading').hide()` executes before the `setTimeout` finishes because the code executes the `setTimeout` call and then the following code, the `setTimeout` does not halt execution of subsequent code. So if you want the `.loading` element to hide after the `#sent` element is hidden, you need to either put it in the same `setTimeout` or in a separate one.

Comment: You call `$(".loading").hide()` which hides all child nodes of `.loading` element.

Comment: try to add ``div`` to include ``h3``

Comment: You also could just have 1 `<span>` for your messages and depending on what is happening in your _ajax call_ just edit the content of that `<span>` and show the proper message

Answer (score 1):

```
  $('.loading').show();
  $("#wait").show();
  $.post(base_url+"index.php/myad/getphonenumber",{uniqueid:id,emailaddress:cemail},function(){
    $("#wait").hide();
    $("#sent").show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#sent").hide();
        $('.loading').hide()
    }, 5000);
  })
```

Comment: It is not necessary to call `$("#sent").hide()`, `#sent` is child node of `.loading`

Answer (score 1):

Call `.hide()` on `.loading`

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".loading").hide()
}, 5000);
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9fvLtm5r/1/